# Finding functions $g_{n}$ with norm $1$ s.t $|\phi(g_{n})|\to||\phi||$ where $\phi(g)=\int_{0}^{1}fg$ for some fixed $f\in C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to do the following exercise:

> Let $f\in C([0,1])$ and define a functional on $C([0,1])$ by  $$
>  \phi(g)=\int_{0}^{1}fg $$
>
> Prove that $\phi$ is is linear and bounded and find functions
>   $\{g_{n}\}$ s.t  $$ ||g_{n}||=1,\,|\phi(g_{n})|\to||\phi|| $$

I have managed to prove that $\phi$ is linear and bounded by $||f||=\int_{0}^{1}|f|$.

Can someone please help me with finding the $g_{n}$'s ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Find continuous $g_n$'s approximating the following *noncontinuous* function
$$g(x):={\rm sgn}(f(x))\,, $$
where $\ \rm sgn\ $ dentoes the *signum* function, ${\rm sgn}(s)=|s|/s\,$ if $s\ne 0$ and ${\rm sgn}(0)=0$.